# lines change places in logfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rubygems, production

I use the logstasher gem to convert my logs into json objects
then I add a line before each log line, 
in development everything works fine. 
In production sometimes the lines change places.

this is how it should be

```
{"index":{"_id":"3cc6221b633bd2bd0a95865e9c0c3dfd"}}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/so_list","format":"*/*","controller":"public","action":"so_list","status":200,"duration":3152.27,"view":246.58,"db":2882.97,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:36Z","@version":"1"}
{"index":{"_id":"4b94f72318d88a8d7c1c5e46e5465246"}}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/ajx_group_items/DY2149","format":"*/*","controller":"public","action":"ajx_group_items","status":200,"duration":118.89,"view":31.89,"db":74.0,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:36Z","@version":"1"}
{"index":{"_id":"b1ceb09e59379be7e26bff6b0d91ccd9"}}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/login","format":"html","controller":"public","action":"login","status":200,"duration":44.24,"view":41.55,"db":1.25,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:36Z","@version":"1"}
```

and sometimes happens this

line 2 should change places with line 3

```
{"index":{"_id":"f6ee3d21d6e424652cdca28e9fdff611"}}
{"index":{"_id":"3c5050daede3f29d0402e888eef02046"}}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/ajx_group_items/DY7100","format":"*/*","controller":"public","action":"ajx_group_items","status":200,"duration":341.08,"view":169.3,"db":157.56,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:37Z","@version":"1"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/ajx_group_items/DY7000","format":"*/*","controller":"public","action":"ajx_group_items","status":200,"duration":334.34,"view":191.42,"db":129.59,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:37Z","@version":"1"}
{"index":{"_id":"f6f59814f6cd45851d529a4efd1d5989"}}
{"method":"GET","path":"/public/ajx_group_items/DY7210","format":"*/*","controller":"public","action":"ajx_group_items","status":200,"duration":305.02,"view":221.0,"db":72.51,"ip":null,"route":null,"request_id":null,"source":"unknown","tags":["request"],"@timestamp":"2018-11-15T18:53:37Z","@version":"1"}
```

my initializer looks like that

```
if LogStasher.enabled?

  LogStasher::ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.class_eval do

    alias :original_process_action :process_action

    def process_action(event)

      # this creates the first line before each log
      log_extra_line = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/logstasher.log")
      hash = {index: {_id: event.payload[:request_id]}}
      log_extra_line.info(hash.to_json) 

      # this adds the log line
      original_process_action(event)
    end

  end

end
```

then I changed the initializer to this
assuming that if i pass both arg to an function and then do the logs it works, but i have still the same problem.

```
if LogStasher.enabled?

  LogStasher::ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.class_eval do

    alias :original_process_action :process_action

    def process_action(event)
      hash = {index: {_id: event.payload[:request_id]}}
      do_logs(hash, event)
    end

    def do_logs(elastic_hash, original_log)
      # this creates the first line before each log
      log_extra_line = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/logstasher.log")
      log_extra_line.info(elastic_hash.to_json) 
      # this adds the log line
      original_process_action(original_log)
    end

  end

end
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initializer, in the elastic_hash I added the event.
The new hash has first the index then the event.
Then i do

```
log = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/logstasher.log")
log.info(elastic_hash.to_json)
```

with this i create only one line for each log, including index and event
and it works

In this case I wouldn't need the gem logsthasher i am sure that it would work different too

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your server's concurrency. When run locally, by default Rails servers run a single thread. In production, they are usually multi-threaded. The log lines are coming in out-of-order because they belong to different requests.

Take a look at [the rails docs on threading and concurrency](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html#automatic-concurrency) for more info.

Comment: Hi @Cara McCormack
i was reading the link, but i still don't know how to solve that

Comment: @mat's - it depends on what you're actually trying to solve. Log lines not appearing in order is usually expected in multithreaded systems. I'd recommend also logging the request ID and using some sort of log parser if you need to track individual requests through the flow in order. Otherwise, you could run a single-threaded server in production as well, although there will obviously be performance penalties.

Comment: what i really wanted to do is add before each log a index.
and then import the log to elasticsearch.
is there a better way to do that ?